Hinting a known feasible solution to a MILP solver with Google OrTools mathopt in Python
I have been going through the online documentation and the samples available on Github, but I was not able to find an example on how to provide an initial solution (or warm start, or solution hint, depending on the preferred synonym) to a compatible MILP solver when modelling through OrTools mathopt in Python.
Would you have a simple example available for this ?
Note if that helps that I am working with OrTools version 9.10.
Thanks a lot !
(I tried going through both the documentation and the source code, I found the SolutionHint class but I don’t know how to use it)
PS : not being sure of the preferred channel for such a question I also posted on github so here is the reference to the page:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/4265
